# is it possible to modify this sentence as below ？

Tags: sentence-construction

> Position the tree however you like, creating the different shapes and angles by rotating and moving the branches.

Is it possible to modify this sentence as below?

> **Positioning** the tree however you like, **create** the different shapes and angles by rotating and moving the branches.

Comment: Do you need the "the" before "different shapes?" Specifically, are there certain shapes to be created? If it's not referring to previously mentioned shapes, the "the" has no anchor.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in meaning but they're so similar that I can't imagine how they would have any effective difference to me in what one would do with the instructions given here.

In the first, the main instruction is to position the tree, with the rest being details on how. In the second, the main instruction is to create shapes. Since the first sentence has the imperative as the first word, here's a comparison where your modified sentence is rearranged to also put the imperative first.

> Position the tree however you like, creating the different shapes and angles by rotating and moving the branches.
>
> Create the different shapes and angles by rotating and moving the branches, positioning the tree however you like.

Now another form comes to mind, where both are imperatives. This detaches the one action from the other. If it's a sequence, where positioning comes first, then creating shapes is done afterward, or if the second part details the the first instruction, then this is simpler and more straightforward as two sentences:

> Position the tree however you like. Create the different shapes and angles by rotating and moving the branches.

The small modifications each shift the focus by some amount. One of these probably instructs the physical process described more accurately or clearly than the others.